# How to refactor Ruby methods to pass Rubocop tests while also being DRY

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I'm working on a game of Twenty-One as part of the Launch School course (think of the game as a lightweight version of Blackjack).

I need to properly refactor my own code to keep it DRY while also passing all of the Rubocop tests. I'm currently using Rubocop version 0.85.0 (this version is required by the course).

With my game, I'm storing all of my data in a hash called Keep Score:

```
keep_score = { 'player_cards' => [], \
               'dealer_cards' => [], \
               'player_card_values' => [], \
               'dealer_card_values' => [], \
               'player_points' => 0, \
               'dealer_points' => 0, \
               'player_move' => '', \
               'dealer_move' => '', \
               'end_game' => false }
```

So far my code works, and I've done a lot of refactoring so far, but I need to refactor these two methods further to make the code more DRY, while still passing the Rubocop tests.

I have two methods, one `convert_face_cards` that converts kings, queens, and jacks (aces handled separately). Then there's a separate method, `add_integer_points` to handle integer values on the cards:

```
def convert_face_cards(keep_score)
  keep_score['player_points'] = 0
  keep_score['dealer_points'] = 0

  keep_score['player_card_values'].each do |card|
    if card == "jack" || card == "queen" || card == "king"
      keep_score['player_points'] += 10
    end
  end
  keep_score['dealer_card_values'].each do |card|
    if card == "jack" || card == "queen" || card == "king"
      keep_score['dealer_points'] += 10
    end
  end
end

def add_integer_points(keep_score)
  keep_score['player_card_values'].each do |card|
    if card.is_a? Integer
      keep_score['player_points'] += card
    end
  end
  keep_score['dealer_card_values'].each do |card|
    if card.is_a? Integer
      keep_score['dealer_points'] += card
    end
  end
end
```

While this code works from a technical perspective, I'm failing the Rubocop testing. The `convert_face_cards` method is returning an error: `Cyclomatic complexity for convert_face_cards is too high. [7/6]`.

My code is clearly not as DRY as it could be. In the `convert_face_cards` method, for example, I'm essentially running the `each` method the same way on both the `player_card_values` hash key as well as the `dealer_card_values` hash key.

But I'm not sure how to further condense these methods. Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def convert_face_cards(keep_score)
  players = keep_score['player_card_values'].select { |card| card == "jack" || card == "queen" || card == "king" }
  dealers = keep_score['dealer_card_values'].select { |card| card == "jack" || card == "queen" || card == "king" }

  keep_score['player_points'] = players.length * 10
  keep_score['dealer_points'] = dealers.length * 10
end
```

Comment: this could still be more DRY

Comment: we can put card types in a variable: 
...
card_types = %w(jack queen king)
players = keep_score['player_card_values'].select { |card| card_types.include? card }
...

Answer (score 0):

Since the logic of counting face cards is the same whether it is a player or the dealer, you can extract that into its own method to make things a bit DRYer.

```
def convert_face_cards(keep_score)
  keep_score['player_points'] = count_faces(keep_score['player_card_values'])
  keep_score['dealer_points'] = count_faces(keep_score['dealer_card_values'])
end

def sum_faces(cards)
  faces = cards.select { |card| face?(card) }
  faces.length * 10
end

def face?(card)
  %w[jack queen king].include?(card)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using a Hash to store this data and writing code which loops over the hashes. You should be using data structures which contains this knowledge as methods.

For example:

```
Card = Struct.new(:value) do
  def score
    case value
    when :king, :queen, :jack
      10
    when :ace
      1
    else
      value
    end
  end
end

CARDS = [
  :ace,
  :king,
  :queen,
  :jack,
  10,
  ... # other cards here
  2
].map { |card| Card.new(card) }

player_cards = []
dealer_cards = []

def score(cards)
  cards.sum(&:score)
end
```